# Could a post-no-deal-Brexit UK urgently join EFTA and access the ESM that way?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, efta

[EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) is a free-trade organisation of Iceland, Norway, Switzerland, and Liechtenstein.  Three of those are members of the [EEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area), Switzerland has bilateral agreements with the [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union), such that all participate in the [ESM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market).  Is it possible to join [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) without joining [EEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area) or making agreements with the [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union)?  Although [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) is in principle an independent organisation from the [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union), [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) members have access to the [ESM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market) so I would expect that the [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) might have a say in [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) membership.  How does joining [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association) work in practice?

For example, suppose the United Kingdom leaves the [EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) without any deal, and then, perhaps after a change of government, decides that the disruption to trade is causing unacceptable economic and societal damage, and decides to urgently join [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association).  What would it take to do so and would it, by itself, restore free trade between the UK and the [ESM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market)?

Comment: Just in case somebody misses the first link for the acronyms? ;)

Comment: @janh I discovered that one can reuse links `[eu]` and `[eu]` with at the bottom `eu: https://...` rather than  writing `[eu][1]` and `[eu][1]` with at the bottom `[1]: https://...` and got carried away with wanting to this feature I found after some 7 years on Stack Exchange ;-)

Comment: Isn't the `urgent` part mostly speculation? Any deal seems unlikely to suit every country, which means there will inevitably need to be some negotiation. How long that takes depends on how easily the parties are willing or able to compromise. How long that will take we don't know (too many factors at play, I think).

Comment: @JJJ Yes, anything relating post-Brexit or post-no-deal-Brexit is mostly speculation, considering that we're 7 months away and nothing is clear yet.

Comment: @gerrit it's mostly the `urgent` part. The rest of the question to me reads like `what would it take for a third country to join EFTA to access the ESM?` Because it refers to brexit we know a few more things about that third country. Maybe I'm nitpicking a bit too much. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All current EFTA members either are EEA members or have extensive bilateral agreements with the EU, which are deemed necessary for the agreement to work. Note [how the EU reacted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_immigration_initiative,_2014#European_Union_reactions) when Switzerland held their recent immigration referendum.

From this precedent, it seems that the EU would be unlikely to accept an end run around the EU rules through the EFTA route.

Comment: Wasn't there talk about Canada joining (or being an associate of) EFTA? For some reason they did not follow it up.